# Rails: Javascript runs from one file but not another

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In rails I have two js files, one called welcome.js and one called about.js. I have the same code in them. I am using require_tree . in the application.js

welcome.js:

```
var loadw = function() {
  console.log("Hello from welcome js!");
}

$(document).ready(loadw); // for regular page load
$(document).on('page:load', loadw); // for turbolink
```

about.js:

```
var loada = function() {
  console.log("Hello from about js!");
}

$(document).ready(loada); // for regular page load
$(document).on('page:load', loada); // for turbolink
```

I have two pages right now, my home page and a calc page which has a calculator written in Javascript (that js file also has $(document).ready functions like about.js and welcome.js, if that matters.) The JS output in the console on the browser when I load the respective pages is:

Loading home page:

```
"Hello from about js!"
```

Loading calculator page:

```
"Hello from about js!"
"Hello from welcome js!"
```

My question is why doesn't the code from welcome.js run when I load home page? What I was trying to do originally is add code to highlight some buttons when they are clicked, and I added this code to welcome.js but it wouldn't work, except when I loaded the calculator page, but worked if I put it in about.js (the buttons are in the header). After a couple hours of trying to debug this I am here - I removed everything but console.log and it's still happening. I am new to rails and I'm probably missing something really simple. I'm debating whether or not to get rid of require_tree and load js files only wherever they're needed, and see if that resolves the issue, but I shouldn't have to do that, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... There was some error occurring in my calc.js when loading pages other than the calc page (because of missing elements in those pages). Because of this error, all the js files after calc.js (welcome.js) weren't loaded properly, but about.js was, because it came before calc.js.

I added this to my application.js

```
//= stub calculator.js
```

then added it separately using javascript_include_tag in my calc page.

Then I got an error saying asset won't be served unless I put it in precompile list in config/initializers/assets.rb, so I did that and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at all, but sometimes javascript get confused when semicolons are missing. Being that only the first (in alphabetical order) function is executed, it seeems to be related to the syntax of the concatenated file.

Try to add semicolons after your function definitions, like

```
var loadw = function() {
  console.log("Hello from welcome js!");
};
```

and run it again.